# Custom Filter Stops working after count of filter value 1013, in Apache Solr Search

Tags: search

I am using [Search API Mutli](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_multi) module to search on multi indexes all together. I need to implement custom permissions on search result set which basically is a filter by node id user has permission to view, for which I implemented hook_search_api_multi_query_alter, the code looks like

```
function mymodule_search_api_multi_query_alter(SearchApiMultiQueryInterface $query) {
  // Get current user connections to filter search search results by.
  global $user;
  $connections = get_allowed_users($user->uid, array(1), 'requester_id');
  $related_nodes = get_allowed_nodes($user->uid);
  $filter = $query->createFilter('OR');
  foreach ($related_nodes as $related_node) {
    $filter->condition("test_content_index:nid", $related_node);
  }
  foreach ($connections as $connection) {
    $filter->condition("test_users_index:uid", $connection);
  }
  $query->filter($filter);
}
```

The two helper functions used in the hook get_allowed_nodes() get_allowed_users() returns allowed uids and nids which the current user is allowed to view, then with help of custom filter I am trying to filter the search results and everything work as expected till count of $related_nodes is less than 1013. The time count reaches to 1014 I get no results found in search result.

I am using apache_solr as search server.